# Usage of awk to search for string that contains characters

Tags: awk

I am facing an issue of searching through lines of text in a text file.

Currently, I am using this command

```
check=`awk -F : -v "title=$title" 'tolower($1) ~ tolower(title)' test.txt`
```

It works fine when the strings are pure alphabetic characters. Assuming the text file contains 3 lines of string which are

```
C++ Programming in 21 Days
C## Programming in 21 Days
C Programming in 21 Days
```

When I do a partial search for just a letter `C`, 3 of the results will be displayed, which is what I want, however, if I keyed in `C++ P`, my program will return text not found. And if i key in `C++`, all 3 results will be displayed as well.

But the funny thing is, if I search for `C## P`, my program will return `C## Programming in 21 Days` found.

I can't seem to find out what is causing this error, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "+" is getting treated as a regular expression.

```
$ title="C++ P"
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'tolower($1) ~ tolower(title)' test.txt
C Programming in 21 Days
$ title="C.. P"
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'tolower($1) ~ tolower(title)' test.txt
C++ Programming in 21 Days
C## Programming in 21 Days
```

If you're only interested in matching the start, you could use

```
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'tolower(substr($0,0,length(title))) == tolower(title)' test.txt
```

Or to match anywhere within the line

```
$ title="C"
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'index(tolower($0),tolower(title))' test.txt
C++ Programming in 21 Days
C## Programming in 21 Days
C Programming in 21 Days
$ title="C++ P"
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'index(tolower($0),tolower(title))' test.txt
C++ Programming in 21 Days
$ title="C## P"
$ awk -F: -v "title=$title" 'index(tolower($0),tolower(title))' test.txt
C## Programming in 21 Days
```

Comment: is there anyway i can do so that it would be treated as a literal character ? And if `C++ P` is entered, no result would be found.

Comment: tried it, didn't work, even keying in a `C` doesn't return any result

Comment: @Zac Steve is using `gawk`

Comment: it worked but this time it couldn't display the result, do i have to change my code that does the displaying as well, the code is `awk -F : -v title="$title" 'BEGIN { OFS = ", "} tolower($1) ~ tolower(title) { printf "%s,%s,$%.2f,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' test.txt` I have $1~$5 for displaying other data that is attached to the title

Comment: never mind, i changed the `tolower`, it works now, thank you very much

Comment: `title` is unnecessarily being invoked by `tolower()` for each record being processed.  It only needs to be set once. It is better to initialize it in the BEGIN block - eg.`BEGIN{ title=tolower(title) }`

Answer (score 5):

`tolower(title)` is handled as regular expression:

- `C++` matches the character `C` literally (case sensitive)

  - Quantifier: `++` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back [possessive]
- `C` matches the character `C` literally (case sensitive)
- `C##` matches the characters `C##` literally (case sensitive)

To get the right result for `C++` you need the pattern `C\+\+`

---

*Examples*

```
% title="C\+\+"                                                
% awk -F : -v "title=$title" 'tolower($1) ~ tolower(title)' foo
C++ Programming in 21 Days
```

or shorter

```
% awk '/[Cc]\+\+/' foo 
C++ Programming in 21 Days

% awk '/[Cc]##/' foo  
C## Programming in 21 Days

% awk '/[Cc] /' foo
C Programming in 21 Days
```

or with an external variable

```
% title='C## P'
% awk '/'"$title"'/' foo   
C## Programming in 21 Days

% title='C\+\+ P'                        
% awk '/'"$title"'/' foo 
C++ Programming in 21 Days

% title='C\+\+ P'
% check=$(awk '/'"$title"'/' foo) 
% echo $check
C++ Programming in 21 Days
```

and so on

Comment: Wow!  Why this isn't the accepted answer, I don't know!